# Adding Excel Watermark using OfficeOpenXml / epplus

Tags: excel, watermark, epplus

Here's my problem..
I have a set of excel files in windows folder that needs to be watermarked using c#. I am already using epplus.
Is there any option to add watermark to excel using epplus?.
Any other ideas is much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Since AFAIK excel does not support a true watermark you will have to fake it.  This might help: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Mimic-a-watermark-in-Excel-5881607e-d76a-43a0-9ff5-6d63653f12bf?CTT=1&CorrelationId=88a2417e-66fc-484a-b5e9-ac3ec80cf463&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US.  Basically, 2 ways: with a picture or with Word Art.  Pictures are mostly supported by Epplus so that should be doable but a bit messy since you need an extra resource.  Word Art is not so much and may require VBA which is less then ideal as well.  See what you can come up with and if you get stuck, post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer... below is the working code block.. may help someone..

```
using System;
using System.Resources;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Configuration;
using VBIDE = Microsoft.Vbe.Interop;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using OfficeOpenXml.Drawing;
using OfficeOpenXml.Style;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Excel.Application xlApp;
                Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
                Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
                object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

                xlApp = new Excel.Application();
                xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath.Text, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
                xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);


                foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet wSheet in xlWorkBook.Worksheets)
                {
                    //Messagebox.show(wSheet.Name.ToString());
                    wSheet.SetBackgroundPicture("http://localhost/QA_red.png");


                }

                xlApp.Caption = "QA Tested";

                xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
                xlApp.Quit();

                releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
                releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
                releaseObject(xlApp);
            }

private void releaseObject(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
                obj = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                obj = null;
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to release the Object " + ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }
```